# "Agile web development with rails" book: CSS not applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

I just started diving into the world of Rails by reading the well known pragmatic book shelf book "Agile web development with rails".

So far I did follow all the examples, but now I am stuck on page 85 (pdf version) where a custom CSS is supposed to be added to the project.

I put the css file (which can be obtained [here](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/rails4/code/rails30/depot_b/public/stylesheets/depot.css) ) in the "/public/stylesheets/" folder.

But when I visit the /products page in the browser the CSS **IS NOT** applied to the products listing page. All the content of the page shows up, just the CSS formatting is missing. The page is generated by [this](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/rails4/code/rails30/depot_b/app/views/products/index.html.erb) .erb file.

Did any of you experience the same problem when following the examples in the book? Does anybody have an idea what's going wrong?

Thank you so much for your help & enjoy the day!

tobi

Comment: Yes, several times - no change!

Comment: Great, putting it in the /app/assets/stylesheets folder did save the problem!!!

Comment: Quite a lot of changes happened from Rails 2.x to 3.x, and you can expect to run into other problems, unless you obtain the most recent version of the book

Comment: Just want to second the "use most recent version" advice.  Using old books is a very good way to introduce a lot of needless pain and confusion into the learning rails process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest edition of this book is for Rails 3.2 (with Asset Pipeline). You should put your stylesheet under `/app/assets/stylesheets`.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Agile web development with Rails - 4th edition. I was able to solve this problem by including  `<%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application", :media => "all"%>` inside `/app/view/layouts/application.html.erb` and having the `depot.css.scss` file in `app/assets/stylesheets/depot.css.scss`. This worked perfectly for me.