# RoR Agile Web Dev 4 CSS not loading

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-1.9.3

I am new to RoR and I am following the *Agile Web Development with Rails 4* book and I am to the point where we add CSS styling to the store front page (page 135 *"8.1 Iteration C1: Creating the Catalog Listing"*).

However, I did exactly as the book stated but the CSS style is not being loaded when I load the page.
I did some research and from what I understand, everything is correct.
Does anyone see anything wrong or what I need to add?

I have tried everything here but nothing worked: [Agile web development with rails” book: CSS not applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071207/agile-web-development-with-rails-book-css-not-applied)

**UPDATE** Looks like the application is using `/assets/scaffold.css.scss` for styling. If I go to this file a change colors, they reflect on the `StoreControllers` view!!??  What is wrong here??!!
I cannot figure out why the application is using the incorrect stylesheet...

BTW I also ran `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and made sure the assets were included in `public/assets/` folder

Here is my code:
**Depot/app/assets/stylesheets/store.css.scss**

```
.store {
  h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    font: 150% san-serif;
    color: #226;
    border-bottom: 3px dotted #77d;    
  }

  .entry {
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #77d;
    min-hieght:100px;    

    img {
      width: 80px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      position: absolute;
    }

    h3 {
      font-size: 120%;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      margin-left: 100px;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      color: #227;
    }

    p,div.price_line{
      margin-left: 100px;
      margin-top: 0.5em;
      margin-bottom: 0.8em;
    }
    .price{
      color: #44a;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-right: 3em;
    }
  }
}
// Place all the styles related to the Store controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
```

**Depot/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Application</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body class=​'<%= controller.controller_name%>'>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**Depot/app/controllers/store/store_controller.rb**

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.order(:title)

  end
end
```

**Depot/app/views/store/index.html.erb**

```
<% if notice %>
<p id= "notice" ><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
<div class= ".entry" >
<%= image_tag(product.image_url)%>
<h3><%= product.title %></h3>
<%= sanitize(product.description)%>
<div class= "price_line" >
    <span class= "price" ><%= product.price %></span>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**Depot/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

**Depot/config/environments/production.rb**

```
Depot::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb'] 
  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end

Depot::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb'] 
  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

Comment: what's the full path of store.css.scss?

Comment: **Depot/app/assets/stylesheets/store.css.scss** here you go

Comment: it does seem correct, do `css` changes you make in `application.css` apply? Like try setting `body {background-color: purple;}`

Comment: No, any changes in `application.css` does not apply. I added `{background-color: purple;}` to `application.css` and nothing changed. I even restarted the rails server with no different result.

Comment: Ye that sucks... It seems to be correct, and do changes in application.html apply?

Comment: Yes, if I add `<style>
body {background-color:lightgray}
h1   {color:blue}
p    {color:green}
</style>`
Into the heading and add `<h1>This is a heading</h1>` into the body, the colors change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved it for me. 
[CSS is not loading in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422475/css-is-not-loading-in-app)

Be sure to test your CSS with something more obvious, like

color: red;

somewhere. The agile book is only aligning the text here. It could be easily missed.